# What is the location of session cookies in IE7?

Tags: session, internet-explorer-7, cookies, location

Should I be able to see per-session cookies, created by IE7 (on Vista) here:

C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files

That is where my standard cookies are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session cookies are stored in memory

Answer (score -1):

**Persistent Cookies vs. Session Cookies**

Cookies are either stored in memory (session cookies) or placed on your hard disk (persistent cookies). Persistent cookies are written to the Cookies folder under either your user profile folder or the Windir\Cookies folder. The Temporary Internet Files index is updated with pointers to the actual cookies files.

**First-Party and Third-Party Cookies**

First-party cookies are cookies that are associated with the host domain. Third-party cookies are cookies from any other domain.