# View IE7 per-session cookies

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-7, session-cookies

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191944/what-is-the-location-of-session-cookies-in-ie7/2191952#2191952) answer, IE7 stores session cookies in memory and doesn't store them on the local filesystem.

Is there any way to view the session cookies that IE7 is currently storing in memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the IE developer toolbar, it has a "view cookie information" option under the cache menu.